# unset target directory after copying a file in vim netrw

Tags: vim, directory, target, unset, netrw

It is well known that vim's netrw extension allows one to manage files directly inside vim. For example to copy a file using the following key strokes in vim:

```
mf (to mark each file)
mt (to set the current directory as the target)
mc (to copy the marked files into the target)
```

However, after all of that is done, the target directory is still set in the netrw headers at the top:

```
"   Copy/Move Tgt: /home/...
```

I want to unset the target directory because I don't want to accidentally copy other marked files to the previously targeted directory. I would rather netrw prompt me after my intentions are complete.

However, I can't seem to find this answer anywhere online.

How can I unset the target directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the vim :help docs it states:

```
  * Also, if the cursor is in the banner, then the netrw window's 
    currently displayed directory is used for the copy/move-to target.
    Unless the target already is the current directory.  In which case,
    typing "mf" clears the target.
```

However, this is not true. Typing `mf` will only mark or unmark files if your cursor is on that file.

I did, however, find through trial and error that if you place your cursor in the banner (the commented section at the top of netrw), and then type `mt` twice, this actually does clear the target directory.

So:

Place cursor anywhere in the banner, and type:

```
mtmt
```

The target directory inside the banner will disappear.